# Python: 4 words before a substring if they exsist

Tags: python

I want to have 4 words a particular word. if there are only 3 wrords before I want the 3 words to be printed.

Example: 
input: There is a bad CAT sitting on the wall
output: is a bad

line is having the sentance.

```
if 'CAT' in line: 
        print(line.split('CAT')[0].split()[len((line.split('CAT')[0]))-3): len(line.split('CAT')[0])])
```

Can you let me know if I am missing anything and if there is any other efficent way.

Planning to do line.split(CAT)[0] to get all the data before cat.
again on that I want to getoutput of [0] starting at len-3 to len.
Its giving Error am I missing anything.
also can I add a condition if there are only 2 words print only 2

Comment: Since you want 4 words, shouldn't the output be `There is a bad` instead of `is a bad`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. If you want to get the three words before `D` in a string `S`, defaulting to fewer words if there's less than three available, you can use this:

```
S.split(D)[0].split()[-3:]
```

Examples:

```
>>> S = 'There is a bad CAT sitting on the wall'
>>> S.split('CAT')[0].split()[-3:]
['is', 'a', 'bad']
>>> S = 'The bad CAT is sitting on the wall'
>>> S.split('CAT')[0].split()[-3:]
['The', 'bad']
```

Of course, if you wish to join this back into a string, you can use:

```
' '.join(S.split(D)[0].split()[-3:])
```

This can also be accomplished using regular expressions, but I doubt it would offer much better performance.

Comment: I hope to never see `' '.join(S.split(D)[0].split()[-3:])` in production code. Me: "What does the code do?" Developer: "It joins strings that are split to a maximum of 3 from the back after splitting the string by D." Me: "Sure, got it. You can leave immediately."

Comment: That's a very fair point. I tried to respond to the specific case as precisely as possible, but there's no denying that it's not very legible (let alone pretty) code.

Comment: Thank you. after using -3 it solved and made the code better

Comment: @MLlearner: why shouldn't `join()` be good? What's the problem?

Comment: np Thanks ..was thinking about performance ..but I think I am fine

Comment: CAT will be used even if it is part of a a word, eg input = `'The bad CATTLE are sitting on the CAT`, output = `The bad`.

Comment: @Deepstop has an excellent point here. If there's any chance at all that the search string might be part of another word, their solution is better.

Answer (score 2):

Split the line at the start, then find the index of the word you want in the resulting list. You can then slice the list (making sure that you don't start the slice at less than zero), and join it back together again. If there are fewer than 3 words preceding it will only show what is there.

```
line = "There is a bad CAT sitting on the wall"
sline = line.split(' ')
if 'CAT' in sline:
    pos = sline.index('CAT')
    print(' '.join(sline[max(0, pos-3):pos]))
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, trying to do all this in one line makes things too confusing. I recommend that you break it up into smaller parts.

```
if line.find('CAT') != -1:
    words = line.split('CAT')[0].strip().split(' ')
    print(words[max(len(words) - 3, 0):])
```

Explanation of some things:

- Yes, some people will think `'CAT' in line` is more Pythonic, but I prefer `line.find('CAT') != -1`, as it won't ignore some errors that might occur if `line` isn't a string. See the [str.find() documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) for details about the function.
- The [strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) in the 2nd line assures that trailing spaces are removed.
- The final line finds the position of the third word before 'CAT', if there is one, and then prints the appropriate words out as a list. As noted in other answers, you and use [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to put them back together as a string if you want.